# Short Circuit evaluation of an if-then-else operator (e.g. ?: in C)

Tags: if-statement, operators, lazy-evaluation, short-circuiting

I need to write a program in any language, that would print 1 if the language uses short circuit evaluation in the if-then-else operator and 0 if the languages does not.

My question is, what does short circuit evaluation in the if-then-else operator mean?

is it simply the lazy evaluation that occurs in the && and || operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone faces a similar assignment/ would like to know more about short circuiting of the if operator in C:
First, Lets mark each part of the if operator as follows:

if(Expression)? BlockA : BlockB;

Now, in PL C, which follows short circuiting of the if-then-else operator, if the Expression is evaluated to true, then **only** BlockA is evaluated, otherwise **only** BlockB is evaluated

Lets assume now that C doesn't follow short circuiting, What happens is that **both** BlockA and BlockB are evaluated regardless of the evaluation result of the Expression (Sounds stupid and dangerous, but apparently that's how it works)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this question correctly, then yes. In languages that implement this, if you had a statement like

```
if (A || B || C || D)
```

the runtime would stop evaluating as soon as it found a statement that was true. For example, if A and B are false but C is true, it would evaluate A, B, and C but not D. This is important if you do something like this:

```
if (a != null && a.ToString() == "abc")
```

The short-circuit behavior means that the second half of this if statement won't be executed if `a` is, in fact, `null`, which is critical because if that wasn't the case then this statement could throw a null reference exception. If it wasn't for that you'd have to do something like

```
if (a != null) {
   if (a.ToString() == "abc") {
      // ...
```

which is obviously a lot less concise.

&& behaves in a similar way:

```
if (A && B && C && D) ...
```

If `A` is `false`, for example, why bother to check the rest of the expressions?

In terms of the assignment, I'll give you a hint: what would happen if you had a side effect in one of the expressions?

Comment: thanks for your explanation, just to make sure I got it all right, would the following code do the trick?  
    int a=0;
    ( 1 || (a=1) )? printf("%d",1-a ) : printf("1");   
when ran on C compilers, it prints 1 because C uses short circuit, but if C didn't use the short circuit on the if-operator, the output would be 0, right?

Comment: @SirajOtman My C's a little rusty and I'm not sitting in front of an IDE but if I remember correctly "1" will evaluate to "true" (correct me if I'm wrong) so it should just evaluate the whole thing.

Comment: 1 does convert to true, but since the C uses short circuit it shouldn't (and it doesn't, I tried it) evaluate the whole string. My question was, if the language did evaluate the whole if-statement , would the output be 0?